# What locks are acquired for each graph action

Tags: neo4j

Having issues with deadlocks on a real-time, transactional, multi-user neo4J embedded system.  Can you point me to documentation which will spell out what locks are acquired for each graph action - I'm especially concerned with adding and deleting relationships as that seems to cause most of the deadlocks.

e.g.
**Add relationship**: write locks placed on both end nodes (is it true that write locks are also placed on all relationships that exist for both end nodes?)

**Delete relationship**: write locks placed on relationship and both end nodes (is it true that write locks are also placed on all relationships for both end nodes?).
Why do the end nodes need to be locked during a relationship deletion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you add a relationship, the graph locks the nodes involved. You can get a deadlock if you lock items in an unpredictable fashion. For me, I had a one-to-many relationship create, so we could order out many nodes by Node ID and this prevented deadlocks for us.

When you delete, it's more complicated. It locks the nodes involved, but under the covers stores the all the relationships as a doubly linked list, so when you remove a relationship you have to lock the previous and the next links so you can link them together without issue. This is something you cannot predict, as you don't really have any ability to get these ID's under the covers.

Your best bet is to do a deadlock retry policy. Do a `try{}catch(DeadlockDetectedException){}`  and if you catch the deadlock exception, retry(I did this by putting the entire operation in a while loop that wouldn't break until the operation I wanted was free of deadlocks).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experiences.  Is there any documentation on specific locks that are acquired on each action?  If not, it would be helpful to my evaluation of the product.  I need both an analytic and real time update system!  I know neo4j says that's what their product provides but I can't just wrap every property update in a while true loop and hope it eventually works.  Our system has hundreds of simultaneous users who demand high performance.  Anyone else out there with the same situation?

Comment: There is no specific documentation other than digging in the source code, which is how I discovered this happens. You don't have to wrap every transaction, but deletes are the tricky ones. The while loop doesn't spend a lot of time unless you have a long pausing operation, typically my deadlocks resolve after 1 retry.

Answer (score 1):

Adding and removing relationships also requires updating both nodes references to what relationships they have. In other words, adding and removing relationships implies writes to the nodes of both ends. Therefore Neo4j needs to take write locks for all three entities.

The documentation is unfortunately out of date, it seems. There is more to locking in Neo4j than what that page reveals, especially now that it has support for things like unique constraints.

Nicholas advice about trying to order the entities by their id, that you want to write to, is worth trying. You can also try to split things out in the graph, such that transactions that would otherwise conflict are less likely to work on the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Found this http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-locking.html which covers some basic info but does not mention linked lists of relationships